# Determining if grammar meets LL(1) requirements

Tags: bnf

I have a BNF for a recursive descent parser. One of the steps to solving this is to verify that the grammar is LL(1), but I keep coming up with verification that it is not.

The BNF in question, or more specifically, the exact area I'm having an issue:

```
<S>           ->      start <vars> <block>
<block>       ->      begin <vars> <stats> end
<vars>        ->      e | id = number <vars>
<stats>       ->      <if> | <block> | <loop> | <assign>
```

There is more to this, but these are the only productions that are relevant to this question, I believe.

My approach to solving this is to compute FIRST of the right hand sides of those productions that have a choice. If there is no choice, I skip, as I know they are already k=0.

```
FIRST(e | id = number <vars>) = {e, id} // Since it produces the empty set, I must also compute follow.

FOLLOW( e | id = number <vars> ) = FOLLOW(<vars>)
```

Non-terminal 'vars' appears in 2 productions:  and , and is followed by two nonterminals: 'block' and 'stats'

```
FIRST(<block>) = {begin}
FIRST(<stats>) = { ... begin ... } // contains all terminals
```

Now, my problem. In computing the FOLLOW(), I have found two begin tokens, which leads me to say that this grammar is not LL(1). However, I don't believe that the answer to this exercise is that it is not possible to create a recursive descent parser, so I believe that I've made an error somewhere or that I have executed the algorithm incorrectly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've correctly found that FOLLOW(*var*) = FIRST(*block*) ∪ FIRST(*stats*).  These are all sets, so when you compute the union of the two first sets (each of which contains `begin`), you end up with just a single `begin`.  As long as neither of these sets ends up containing `id`, everything is fine and your grammar is still LL(1).

Comment: I see. So as long as there's no intersection between my FIRST sets, I have no issue?